# MVC - replace existing if same URL already open in a tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue here in my MVC application. Some external site hits the my mvc site which opens the site in new window and inserts all the data and saves GUID in session. If users hits multiple times through external site, it opens multiple tabs of my sites which ends up sharing the session in all tabs.

Is there a possibility to add a code on master page to check if a specific URL is already opened the it should close or replace the tab url? (for chrome, Mozilla and IE)

E.G. when external site hits my site, it opens with url as [www.secure.abc.no/tbc/Claimadd/AuthorizeClaimAdd?claimIdentifier=cf57ede2-e78c-44b4-8a9b-c63e248862e1](http://www.secure.abc.no/tbc/Claimadd/AuthorizeClaimAdd?claimIdentifier=cf57ede2-e78c-44b4-8a9b-c63e248862e1)

Now if user tries to hit with different claimIdentifier then it should check if 'www.secure.abc.no/tbc/Claimadd/AuthorizeClaimAdd' url is already open in tab and  replace the above url with new one?

Comment: A tab cannot impact another tab in the way you are hoping for.

Comment: You could probably use SignalR (or its underlying technologies) to communicate between open pages/tags within your application.

Comment: You can name and target tabs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453959/how-can-i-set-the-browser-tabs-anchor-target-name-via-javascript but I'm not sure how widely supported it is - or reliable and whether you can control how the tab is opened